# SQL filters in ArcGIS online

Tags: carto, arcgis-online

Is it possible to do SQL filters in ArcGIS online similar to the SQL tab of CartoDB maps?

I want to do an expression on several table fields.

Below is a screenshot of the map control panel that I have.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It is possible.

However, it depends on how the site is set up. Because AGOL costs by the amount of data used on ESRI hosted servers, many opt out of sharing the ability to query publicly. If you are wishing to query AGOL data within your own organization or are wanting to set something up yourself, chances are that you will be able to query. If it's for another organization and you don't see an option to query (or perform calculations, etc), chances are that it's set up so that you cannot.

More about AGOL queries here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/help/index.html#//01560000001z000000

Comment: Thanks. That page is talking about a queries panel. I wonder where the menu/link for that can be found. You may be correct that it is disabled for us.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the map control panel to the original post.

Comment: The query/filter tool has been moved from the right click menu to the icons below the layer name - it's the one with the little funnel second from the right.